# Secrets not being set by Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a set of secrets I'd like my compose file to set to environment variables but when I attempt to run the `compose.yml` file, the terminal states that these variables aren't being set.

My compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  aline-microservices:
secrets:
  mysql-db:
    file: './secrets/MYSQL_DATABASE'
  mysql-pass:
    file: './secrets/MYSQL_PASSWORD'
  mysql-user:
    file: './secrets/MYSQL_USER'
  root-pass:
    file: './secrets/ROOT_PASSWORD'
  db-url:
    file: './secrets/DB_URL'
  jwt:
    file: './secrets/JWT_SECRET_KEY'
  secret-key:
    file: './secrets/SECRET_KEY'
services:
  aline-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/root-pass
      - MYSQL_USER: /run/secrets/mysql-user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/mysql-pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: aline-/run/secrets/mysql-db
    secrets:
      - root-pass
      - mysql-user
      - mysql-pass
      - mysql-db
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", 'mysqladmin', 'ping', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', 'root', '-p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

My file system:

```
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
secrets (folder)
everything else
```

The password resides in `./secrets/ROOT_PASSWORD` as a string:

```
<the password is here>
```

Did I set it up incorrectly?

Comment: Not confident enough in this to make it a full answer but have you tried specifying the files without quotes? Also have you tried this with the files in the same directory (like their docs do) just to see if that works? May be two decent steps to help you triage.

Comment: Neither solution worked, unfortunately.

Comment: If you do `docker secret create my_db_pass db_pass.txt` and look at the contents of the file, does the format match the way you made your files? If not, that may be the issue too.

Comment: When I run this command it just returns a random string of characters. I don't know what it means or how I am supposed to use it.

Comment: it's the secret ID, which is I believe what is supposed to be in the file or env var. I think your file can't just contain the secret in plaintext like that, it has to be a docker secret.

Comment: I ended up removing the secrets, I'll use them at a different point in my project. I appreciate all the answers though, I definitely learned some new things I was not aware of before.